# In what circumstances would using threads benefit a sequential program?

Tags: multithreading, operating-system, sequential

The title pretty well sums up my question. "In what circumstances would using threads benefit a sequential program"?

Comment: Your question is very broad. General answer is: "The benefit will be gained if there are blocks of the code in sequential program which can be run in parallel". But that can be extended to many many paragraphs of text.

Answer (score 0):

there are many reasons and its a bit complicated. So I try to be as precious as possible.

Every programm can be parallelized, but sometimes its not worth.

The Big benefit of multithreading is the usage of all cores. This can lead to an improvement of the performance. In the optimal case, having 2 cores working on a problem will double the execution-speed. But in reality this speed-up will be reduzed by the amount of overhead from the threads:

general overhead:

- thread start/stop
- communication/synchronization

To ignore the start-stop overhead, the life-time of the threads should be as large as possible.

The communication/synchronisation part is the main-problem. There is an an awful lot of complexity here. In short: avoid/reduce the communication between threads. Each thread should work as isolated as possible.

basically its a trade-off between the overhead and parallelism. 
so the key-questions are:

- Do you have performance-problems?
- Do you have access to a multicore?
- Do you need the ease of stack-management (->each TCP-connection on
  different thread)
- Are you willing to test multiple solutions
  (sequential vs. parallel)?

for more information: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gustafson%27s_law